# Laravel validation - missing_if validator

Tags: php, laravel

I have an unconventional case where I have two fields in the request:
`date_before` and `date_after`.
I need to make sure that ONLY ONE of them is filled at all times. There are plenty of examples where at least one field is required but not my specific case.

That is - fail validation if both of them are filled.

So far, the only Laravel validator that could theoretically fit my needs is `missing_if` https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-missing-if (add it to both fields).

However, I could not find a way to make `value` of that rule simply not empty.

Is this kind of challenge achievable using Laravel validation rules?

Comment: ``missing_with`` is what you're looking for: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-missing-with

Comment: Thank you! From the description that is exactly what I need. Somehow missed it when reading myself.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return an error to user that both of fields filled, you need to use `missing_if`.
if you want to exclude field under validation will be excluded from the request data returned by the `validate` and `validated` methods if the anotherfield filled you can use `exclude_if` https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-exclude-if